# How to add id on has error div in form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I used [Jquery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)  ..

If possible to add **unique Id** on each **has-error** div.

I tried but not working... 
**[Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/qOapQQ)**

Example i used '#test'. Each div added #test the same. but i need test1,test2......testn.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#question_form").validate({
    errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
    errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
    focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
      fill: "required",
      radios1: "required",
      radios5: "required",

    },   
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) { // hightlight error inputs
      $(element).closest('.qst_opt_val').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group

      if($('.qst_opt_val').hasClass('has-error')){
                     $('.qst_opt_val').attr('id','test');
                        }    
    },     

    submitHandler: function(form) {
      error.hide();
      form.submit();
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: What should I do to get an error?

Comment: @lshettyl : i didn't get no error... the "#test' added on each has-error div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a quick and dirty way is to loop thru the elements that has the error class, grab the index of the element, add a string plus the index as the ID. Below is the section I modified:

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) { // hightlight error inputs
    $(element).closest('.qst_opt_val').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group

    $('.qst_opt_val.has-error').each(function(index) {
        this.id = "test" + (index+1)
    });

}
```

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5fysyj4k/) with your code.

Comment: @Ishettyl: Works Perfect :)